# Find the form of the quadratic approximation of a function $f$ at a certain point $a$ and find its euclidean normal form

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, quadrics

> Find the form of the quadratic approximation of a function $f$ at a certain point $a$ and find its euclidean normal form.
>
> $f(x,y)=\cos(x)\cos(y)$ and $a=\left(-\frac{\pi}{2}\,\,\,-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^T$

---

I know that the quadratic approximation is:

$$z=T_2(f,x,a)$$

So I calculated $T_2(f,x,a)=xy+\frac{\pi }{2}x+\frac{\pi }{2}y+\frac{\pi^2 }{4}$

Which gives the approximation of$(x:=x_1,y:=x_2,z:=x_3)$:

$$\mathcal{Q}:=\lbrace (x_1,x_2,x_3):x_1x_2+\frac{\pi }{2}x_1+\frac{\pi }{2}x_2+\frac{\pi^2 }{4}-x_3=0\rbrace$$

We can write this as:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 x_1  \\
 x_2  \\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}^T\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & \frac{1}{2}&0\\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0&0\\
0 &0&0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
 x_1  \\
 x_2  \\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}+2\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{\pi}{4}  \\
 \frac{\pi}{4}  \\
-\frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}^T\begin{pmatrix}
 x_1  \\
 x_2  \\
x_3
\end{pmatrix}+\frac{\pi^2 }{4}=0$$

Now we rotate our quadratic approximation so that we get only pure quadratic components:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & \frac{1}{2}&0\\
 \frac{1}{2} & 0&0\\
0 &0&0
\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow A-\lambda=\begin{pmatrix}
 -\lambda & \frac{1}{2}&0\\
 \frac{1}{2} & -\lambda&0\\
0 &0&-\lambda
\end{pmatrix}$$

$\det(A-\lambda)=-\lambda^3+\lambda\frac{1}{4}\Longrightarrow \lambda_{1,2,3}=0;-\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2}$

and our Transformationmatrix $T$ build by the normed eigenvectors is:

$$T=\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0\\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0\\
0 &0&1
\end{pmatrix}=T^{-1}$$

After proper rotation we get:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 y_1  \\
 y_2  \\
y_3
\end{pmatrix}^T\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{1}{2} & 0&0\\
 0 & -\frac{1}{2}&0\\
0 &0&0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
 y_1  \\
 y_2  \\
y_3
\end{pmatrix}+2\left(\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0\\
 \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} & -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}&0\\
0 &0&1
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{\pi}{4}  \\
 \frac{\pi}{4}  \\
-\frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}\right)^T\begin{pmatrix}
 y_1  \\
 y_2  \\
y_3
\end{pmatrix}+\frac{\pi^2 }{4}=0$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{2}y_1^2-\frac{1}{2}y_2^2+\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}y_1-y_3+\frac{\pi^2 }{4}=0$$

Now we can move against the linear part by first rewriting:

$$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}y_1+\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{2}y_2^2-y_3=0\Longleftrightarrow\frac{1}{2}\left(y_1+\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{2}\right)^2-\frac{1}{2}y_2^2-y_3=0$$

And now defining:$\,\,\,\,z_1:=y_1+\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{2},\,\,\,z_2:=y_2,\,\,\,z_3:=y_3$

$\longrightarrow$

$$\frac{1}{2}z_1^2-\frac{1}{2}z_2^2-z_3=0$$

$$\Longleftrightarrow -z_1^2+z_2^2+2z_3=0$$

which is a hyperbolic paraboloid

---

Could someone check for me if every step was correct, or if somewhere I went wrong? That would be great :)

Comment: especially the euclidean normal form needs a verifictaion :) would be nice if someone could tell if the form is correct